# Square root of a complex number given in $z=re^{i\phi}$ form

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

I need to get the square root of a complex number for a problem in optics and this is what I've done:

A given complex number $z=a+bi$ can be rewritten as $z=re^{i\phi}$ where $r=|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\phi =  \arctan (b/a)$.

With this notation, I've noticed that

$$z^2=r^2e^{i2\phi}$$

Therefore would it be coherent to define the square root of a complex number as

$$\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}$$

I would like to know if this always holds or if there's a case where this definition wouldn't be true.

Thanks for the help and sorry for any grammar or spelling mistakes I might have made, english is not my first language.

Comment: [You're wrong about $\phi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). It can't be a function of $b/a$ because it changes when multiplying $z$ by $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Any $\sqrt{z} = \sqrt{a + bi} = \pm\big(x + yi\big)$ for some $x, y$.

This means, if: $z = a + bi$, $\sqrt{z} = \pm \sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$.

However, we know that $-re^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$ is a just negated vector of
$\sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$ (Difference in angle of $\pi$).

Hence, $-\sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}} \to \sqrt{r}e^{i(\frac{\theta}{2} - \pi)}, \theta > 0$ or $ \sqrt{r}e^{i(\pi - \frac{\theta}{2})}, \theta \le 0$ (We are assuming principle arguments here, $(-\pi, \pi])$.

While it is correct to state, $\sqrt{z} = \sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$, it would not be coherent/complete. Rather and informally, $\sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}} \subseteq \sqrt{z}$.